# How can i display fixed number of images in a row on different devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a set of images in a row,I want them to be displayed as 4 images on lg devices,2 images on sm and md devices but I am confused on How to use the grids to achieve this. this is my bootstrap code.you can see the effect [here](https://maheshmnj.github.io)in the skills section.when you resize the screen to sm the images take the complete width of the screen,

How can I make them take 50% of the width only so that 2 images are displayed in a  row.

```css
img{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row pr-3 pt-1 pl-3 pb-3">
  <div class="skill-set col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 pt-3"> 
       <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533883355737-25ab4d1fbefb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e596d702f8053a202b1ce231eaa2f999&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80" alt="Card image cap">
       <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">grid1 </h5>
     
       </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="skill-set col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 pt-3"> 
       <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533883355737-25ab4d1fbefb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e596d702f8053a202b1ce231eaa2f999&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80" alt="Card image cap">
       <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">grid2</h5>
        </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="skill-set col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 pt-3"> 
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533883355737-25ab4d1fbefb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e596d702f8053a202b1ce231eaa2f999&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">grid3</h5>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="skill-set col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 pt-3"> 
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533883355737-25ab4d1fbefb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e596d702f8053a202b1ce231eaa2f999&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
           <h5 class="card-title">grid4</h5>
           </div>
 </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: My guess is you haven't set any css on images to prevent them overflowing the column. please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: I haven't set any css for this code this is a minimal bootstrap code and even complete and I have already verified it before posting, in case you want to test it just add the bootstrap cdn in the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the grid class from `col-md-3` to `col-md-6`